# ADF Dataset Availability

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've worked with Azure Data Factory since it was in preview, but some of the various combinations of flags really confuse me still..

***Situation:*** I've a daily slice interval pipeline with a series of activities (4 in total) that are chained of two external data sources. Currently it all runs fine, but runs right at the end of the slice, i.e. midnight.

The data is actually available @ 7pm *on the day* of the slice, so we don't need to wait.

***Solution:***
So, if i set all external datasources to have:

```
        "external": true,
        "policy": {
            "externalData": {
                "dataDelay": "-05:00:00" // i.e. 24:00 - 5:00 = 19:00
            }
        }
```

will this work?!

Thoughts i have:

- Do i need to set anything in the activity to match?
- I am keen not to actually change the start/end of the actual slice, just make it run "early" when all data is ready.
- Will the output datasets, and all other datasets for that matter in the pipeline also need something set?

The reason i am asking here, is that without having the ability to travel through time, this is a bit of a pain to debug via trial and error, so wnat to sense check with someone :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the data to be ready at the start of the interval. The article on [scheduling in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#dataset-availability-and-policies) should answer your questions and call out the relevant properties you can set on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using 2 additional attributes in output dataset availability section:

```
"availability": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1,
            "offset": "20:00:00",
            "style": "StartOfInterval"
        }
```

The above setting will trigger the pipeline @ 8PM (20:00:00) daily.

Then in Pipeline you need set the start date as [WhateverDate]T**20:00:00Z**